# Histogram highchart series not correctly displaying on the first load in angular application

Tags: angular, highcharts, histogram

I have implemented histogram highchart in angular 4 application. I basically want to enable toggling of the legends. So at any one point of time,one legend would be enabled which means only the series of that legend should be enabled. The toggling works perfectly fine, but the first time the histogram loads it shows a faded background drawn over the selected series. Please note that as soon as i click the legend the series loads fine. I guess the issue is that the series are not correctly being set to visible false. However I tried adding 5 series which contains histogram as well data. So in all looped 10 times to set the visibility of the series. |I need to consider setting the visibility of the histogram and data object
 Could somebody tell me what the problem is ?

This is how it looks now

[image]

This is how it should be

[image]

This is how the series is bound to the histogram. If you see below each series would contain histogram object and data object.

```
@Input() set endingResults(value: Array<EndingSurplus>) {
    let objHistogram;
    let objectData;
    this.results = value;

    this.chartSeries1 = value.map((element, idx) => {

      objHistogram = {
        name: element.strategyName,
        color: element.strategyColor,
        type: 'histogram',
        xAxis: 1,
        yAxis: 1,
        baseSeries: 's' + idx,
        zIndex: -1,
        binWidth: Math.round((Math.max.apply(null, element.data) - Math.min.apply(null, element.data)) / 40)
      };
      objectData = {
        name: 'Data' + idx,
        showInLegend: false,
        data: element.data,
        id: 's' + idx,
      };

     this.chartSeries[2 * idx] = objHistogram;
     this.chartSeries[2 * idx + 1] = objectData;

     if (this.endingHistogramChart) this.endingHistogramChart.redraw();
    });

  }
```

kindly see the logic in the redraw method

```
 redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;

          let seriesLength = this.chart.series.length;
        for (let i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            this.chart.series[i].remove();
        }


        this.series.map(s => {
            if (s !== null) {
                this.chart.addSeries(s,false);
            }
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < this.chart.series.length; i++) {
            if (i > 1) {
                this.chart.series[i].setVisible(false, false);
            } else {
                this.chart.series[i].setVisible(true, true);
                this.chart.series[i].showInLegend = true;
            }
        }

       this.chart.redraw();
    }
```

histogram component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'histogramchart',
    template: '<chart [options]="options" (load)="getInstance($event.context)"></chart>',
    styles: [`
        chart{
              display: block;
              width: 100% !important;
              padding:0;
        }
    `]
})
export class HistogramChartComponent {

    public options: any;
    chart: any;
    @Input() public series: any;

    constructor(private _translate: TranslateService) {

        this.options = {
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'histogram'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                margin: 25,
                itemMarginTop: 0,
                symbolRadius: 0,
                symbolHeight: 20,
                symbolWidth: 20,
                useHTML: true,
                    title: {
                    text: this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.COMMON.GRAPH_LEGEND_TITLE') + ' &nbsp;',
                    margin: 50,
                    style: {
                        fontStyle: 'italic',
                        fontWeight: 'normal',
                        margin: 20
                    }
                },
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function() {
                            for (let i = 0; i < this.chart.series.length; i++) {
                                if (this.chart.series[i].index !== this.index) {
                                    this.chart.series[i].setVisible(false, false);
                                } else {
                                    this.chart.series[i].setVisible(true, false);
                                }
                            }
                            this.chart.redraw();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                }

            },

            xAxis: [{
                title: { text: '' },
                alignTicks: false
            }, {
                title: { text: this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.ESA.GRAPH_XAXIS') },
                alignTicks: false,

            }],

            yAxis: [{
                title: { text: '' }
            }, {
                title: { text: this._translate.instant('CAPTIVES.RESULTS.ESA.GRAPH_YAXIS') },

            }],

            series: [{
                showInLegend: false
            }]

        };
    }

    getInstance(chartInstance): void {
        this.chart = chartInstance;
        this.redraw();
    }

    ngOnChanges(data: any) {
        if (!data.series.currentValue || !this.chart) return;

        data.series.currentValue.map(s => {
            this.chart.addSeries(s);
        });
        this.chart.reflow();
    }

    redraw() {
        if (!this.chart) return;

          let seriesLength = this.chart.series.length;
        for (let i = seriesLength - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            this.chart.series[i].remove();
        }


        this.series.map(s => {
            if (s !== null) {
                this.chart.addSeries(s,false);
            }
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < this.chart.series.length; i++) {
            if (i > 1) {
                this.chart.series[i].setVisible(false, false);
            } else {
                this.chart.series[i].setVisible(true, true);
                this.chart.series[i].showInLegend = true;
            }
        }

       this.chart.redraw();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the source of the black/dark overlapping shape? Setting showInLegend on series might not work - use series.update() instead. Please create a live demo in Plunker or another sandbox for Angular.

Comment: I have resolved this issue. I had to change the check in the redraw method from   if (i > 1)  to   if (i > 0)